# Can't avoid GCs in simple draw loops

Tags: android

I'm trying to test out some different methods of drawing to a Canvas, without triggering garbage collection. Even the most basic examples cause frequent gcs. Example:

```
class Panel extends View {
    private int mX = 0;
    private Paint mPaint = new Paint();

    public Panel(Context context) {
        super(context);
        mPaint.setColor(0xFFFF0000);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
        canvas.drawRect(mX, 0, mX+40, 40, mPaint);
        mX++;

        postInvalidate();
    }
}
```

I get the same result with SurfaceView (lunar lander example). GCs about every 10 seconds or so, pretty jarring in a realtime game. I'm not making any allocations in the draw loop above, so something must be allocated in the canvas etc classes (unfortunately).

I had success with an opengl test, no gcs, but I was hoping to avoid getting into opengl. I'm pretty familiar with it, but it's going to be tough drawing some effects I wanted to achieve using opengl.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

postInvalidate() may have to create an object. Use invalidate() instead, there is no reason to use postInvalidate() here.

Comment: Hi Romain, I think this helped. LogCat shows GC calls still, but from different PIDs than my app. I don't think there's anything we can do about GCs from other processes, right?

Comment: @user291701: "I don't think there's anything we can do about GCs from other processes, right?" -- correct, but they should have muted impacts on your foreground process' performance.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of guessing you should take a look at [what is allocated](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/02/track-memory-allocations.html).

Comment: I've used MAT before, but not sure how I'd use it effectively in this case. I was guessing that the canvas class, or one of the other android sdk classes were making allocations. It would be helpful if MAT could do a diff between to snapshots to only show new allocations.

Comment: Rather than MAT, use DDMS's allocation-tracking capability to see exactly what is being allocated by your app. That is what @mibollma is pointing you to, not MAT.